# VBA on Excel only use one processor, how can I use more?

Tags: excel, cpu-usage

VBA is known to work on only one processor at the same time, so when I run a macro, Excel only uses 50% of CPU instead of totally (dual-core).

Is there a workaround to make VBA use both processors ?

Thanks.

Comment: As I understand it, the short answer is no. Long answer: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2005/11/03/multi-threaded-calculation-in-excel-or-how-calculation-can-become-much-faster-in-excel-12.aspx

Comment: I have ran a huge macro on a dual core with 1 processor, took about 25 minutes to execute, then I ran the same macro on a i7 core , took about 25 minutes.. so the answer is NO. What you can do- its to set priority in the task manager to high - then its seems like its using more than 50%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the problem up across multiple instances of Excel.Applications, that way you could do half in one copy of Excel and half in the other.

I've seen someone doing simulation work in Excel VBA using 8 cores.  A bit of a pain to bring the results back together at the end, but it worked.

Comment: So multiple instances and copy/pasting data in one file. Also is there some VBA interpreter which use multiple CPU cores ? I know Open Office/Libre Office can run VBA macros too.

Comment: Yeah, or writing the data back to a database perhaps (which is what my colleague did).  Not sure about using VBA in different interpreters.  if you're going that far, then why not use VB.Net instead - it has v.good support for multi-threading.

Comment: The thing is I can't use other language other than VBA and the company hosting us (subcontractor) doesn't provide us Visual Studio tools. I was thinking, maybe it could be possible to use LibreOffice VBA Interpreter to speed up processing, but not sure how.

Comment: Best of luck.  That method I mentioned above does work though, so if you get no luck using the interpreter then give it a shot.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no unless you split the workload across multiple Excel instances and recombine the results at the end.
 But the vast majority of cases of slow VBA execution can be speeded up by orders of magnitude:

- switch off screen updating
- set calculation to manual
- read and write excel data using large ranges and variant arrays rather than cell-by-cell
- look closely at the coding in VBA UDFs and bypass the VBE refresh bug
- minimise the number of calls to the Excel object model

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010
Go to File --> Options --> Advanced. 
Scroll down until you see the section for Formulas and you can set the number of processors to be used when calculating formulas. 
This may not have an effect on VBA but it will work for running a formula down an entire column. Its a big time saver when working with large workbooks. Additionally you can go to task manager and right click on excel and set the priority to high so that your machine focuses its energy there.

** This option does not appear to be available for Mac **